# aligned multi-line equation with intertext and block-wise numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I try to reproduce the output that is generated by:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 & = r_1^2 \\
    (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 & = r_2^2 \\
    (x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2 & = r_3^2 \\
    \end{aligned}
    \label{label a}
\end{equation}
Additional lines:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    (x-x_k)^2 + (y-y_k)^2 & = r_k^2     
    \end{aligned}
    \label{label b}
\end{equation}
```

but make the two aligned blocks use the same alignment (as if it was just one align block.
I tried to do this with just one align block + intertext for the line of text in the middle. But this gave me 4 lines of equation with 4 individual numbers which is not desired.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 & = r_1^2 \notag\\
    (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 & = r_2^2     \label{label a}\\
    (x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2 & = r_3^2 \notag
\shortintertext{Additional lines:}
    (x-x_k)^2 + (y-y_k)^2 & = r_k^2
    \label{label b}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\shortintertext` is from `mathtools` package and gives a tighter spacing than `\intertext`.