# Is there any way to keep the alignment of the previous align environment?

Tags: align

Basically, I want to break up an `align` environment with a line or two of comments and then continue with a new `align`, but I want to keep the alignment (aka the positioning of the `&` character) in the same horizontal space as the previous `align`. Is there any way to do that?
Alternatively, is there any way to break out of the `align` environment for a comment in text mode and then break back in?

Comment: Do you just want `\intertext{whatever}`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194113/33514

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59768/adding-multiple-paragraphs-between-aligned-equations/59770#59770

Comment: There is another way involving \phantom, \mathllap and \mathrlap, but \intertext is easier.

Comment: I didn't even know that there was an ```\intertext{}``` command. Yes, that's it, sorry for the duplicate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a duplicate question, for the record the answer is the `\intertext{text here}` command.